# Смена iframe по команде

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Стоит iframe1 и две кнопки. При нажатии на кнопку 2 вместо iframe1 появляется iframe2. При нажатии на кнопку 1 снова появляется iframe1. Как это реализовать с помощью JavaScript? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно, [[@ChessMen](/users/7801/chessmen)](/users/7801/chessmen) , если

> для своего сайта

и в "образовательных целях" то вот код:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
<title>Моё уведомление</title>
<script>
    var urls = ["адрес1","адрес2"];
    var curl = 0;
    function changeURL(frame)
    {
       if(curl == 0)
       {
           frame.src = urls[0];
           curl = 1;
       }
       else
       {
           frame.src = urls[1];
           curl = 0;
       }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="" id="myframe"></iframe>
<input type="button" value="Сменить" onclick="changeURL(document.getElementById('myframe'))">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Менять Src iframe по событию нажатия на кнопку.

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю. Я не представляю как это в коде написать :)

Comment: Спросите что именно вам не понятно, сейчас возникает такое ощущение, что вы в глаза не видели JavaScript

Comment: Сделайте хоть какой то пример, а здесь дальше помогут.
Почитайте про события http://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events.

Comment: Именно здесь как мне прописать? Я просто в джаваскриптах работал только с переменными, ну и с командами `onMouseOut` и `onMouseOver`:

    <script>
    function Super(){
     document.getElementById(). = ;
     document.getElementById(). = ;
    }
    </script>

Comment: почитайте основы Js.Вы получите деньги ,а мы порванные носки.Вы даже не читали мою ссылку,а там работа с событиями

Comment: Спс за ссылку. не увидел. Сейчас попробую разобраться :)